# How to create an actionBar in activity which is extending to other activities?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have created a `BaseActivity`, which is extending all other activites, but now I don't know how to create an action bar there. I was trying, but didn't have luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code of my `BaseActivity`, which is extending all other activities:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());      
        actionBar = getActionBar();

    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_back, R.anim.slide_out_back);
    }

}
```

Comment: use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity, and use a Toolbar inside your layout. Then you can setup in the onCreate method after the setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());  call.

Comment: What did you mean by using toolbar inside layout. Do i need to create a custom toolbar? I'm new in android developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in many ways.

For example you can use a [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) in each layout. Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());     

       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       setupActionBar();
       //....

   }

   //...
}

public MyActivity extends BaseActivity{

    @Override    
    protected int getLayoutResourceId(){
         return R.layout.mylayout;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setupActionBar(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //.....
    }

}
```

In your activity layout you can put your Toolbar:

layout/mylayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout ....>

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
       android:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
       app:popupTheme="@style/MyToolbarPopupTheme" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have managed to create a Toolbar, but i don't know how to find the id of toolbar in BaseActivity because i didn't set content view there of any activity.

Comment: Sorry. Your are right. I've just updated my answer. >The id is in the layout with the toolbar.

Comment: Sorry Gabriel, i'm really newbie, i have created a new layout and named it app_bar and there i implement Toolbar, but i still can't find the id of that toolbar in BaseActivity. Am i doing something wrong?